# How can I get a complete, full background image (no repeat) to show, without using a table in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, css

I'm putting this in a widget in WordPress:

```
<div style="background-image: url('http://www.domain.net/img/subscribe.png'); 
background-repeat: no-repeat;"> </div>
```

But the result is this:

[image: What I'm seeing]

When I want the result to be this:

[image: Desired result]

So it's barely showing the top of the background image I want.  How can I achieve getting the full image -- but of course I don't want it to repeat x, or repeat y?  And should I be using div tags, or something else?  Any guidance in this regard would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you assigned a height to the `div`? Also, if all you're doing is showing an image, an `<img>` tag might be better...

Comment: `background-size: cover` is probably better than `background-repeat`, but either way you'll have to set the size of your `div`.. (are you sure you don't want an `img` tag..?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set that `div`'s width/height to the same size as the background image. I would recommend something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="newsletter-subscribe">
  <!-- any additional content can go here, like a <form> for example -->
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.newsletter-subscribe {
  background-image: url('http://www.domain.net/img/subscribe.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top left;
  width: 400px; /* whatever the picture width is */
  height: 300px; /* whatever the picture height is */
}
```

The reason why you'd put this in a stylesheet, instead of inline, is so that you can more easily apply other styles to your container (ie `div.newsletter-subscribe`), as well as make changes in your stylesheet - instead of in template and/or partial files. Styles are much easier to maintain in a stylesheet than inline.

Comment: Thank you Dward!  I have attempted to implement your solution, which makes complete sense.  Thank you for taking the time to explain.  For some reason, I'm now getting a blank space where the image is supposed to show up.  I double-checked the spelling, the URL of the image, etc., and everything is proper.  I tried flushing my website's cache to no avail.  But I think your solution is the right one -- I'll keep tryin'!

Comment: If you aren't planning on putting any other elements on top of the image (say a form or other text), then it's even easier for you to manage as an image `<img src="" />`. I've setup a demo with two (2) ways to accomplish your goal: http://jsfiddle.net/f9PCd/

Comment: Still working on it, Dward.  Basically, I'm trying to mock what Yoast does in his newsletter on his sidebar: https://yoast.com/ .... uses that background image.  If you'd like to see the URL I'm working on, it's http://www.netprezence.net ...

Comment: Can you please send over an absolute path to the background image you want to use? I'll give you the HTML and CSS for your sidebar.

Comment: Yes ... http://www.netprezence.net/img/subscribe.png ... thanks Dward!  Remember, it has to be a background image.

Comment: .newsletter-subscribe {
  background-image: url('http://www.netprezence.net/img/subscribe.png')
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top left;
  width: 280px; 
  height: 144px; 
}

Comment: Was missing a semicolon, and had another syntax error just in front of it ... found via Chrome Inspector ... that's all it took was a good night's sleep.  Thanks for your help, Dward!

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47449/discussion-between-dward-and-jason-weber)